# Navigation failed after logging in with react-native-fbsdk

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am using the FBSDK to do the registration in react native. I need the name, last name and email in order to pass it to the registration screen and fill the mentioned fields there automatically. Here is my code in login screen:

```
      async _fbAuth() {
        //console.log("that", that);
          let { isCancelled } = await LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile','user_posts', 'email','user_birthday']);
          if ( !isCancelled ) {
              let data = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
              let token = data.accessToken.toString();
            //  await afterLoginComplete(token);
              const response = await fetch(
                  `https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,email,name,first_name,last_name,gender,picture,cover&access_token=${token}`);
              let result = await response.json();
              this.setState({result});
                console.log('result result result ', result);
//navigate to complete the registration. 
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Reg_1', {name: this.state.result.name, email: this.state.result.email, surname: this.state.result.last_name })

          }
          else {
              console.log('Login incomplete');
          }

      }
```

Also I have this button to call the function:

```
<ButtonFB
                 onPress={ this._fbAuth}
                 isLoading={false}
                 isEnabled={true}
                 label={I18n.t("Accedi_con_Facebook")}
                 style={commonStyle.Button}
                 />
```

Everything works fine and the data retrieved well. The only problem is the part of navigation and setSate. My problem is that the 'this' has been lost during the login with the facebook. I got the following warning after doing the login with facebook.

> Possible: Unhandled promise rejection (id:0): type error:
>   this.setState is not a function

I also tried to bind the function of `_fbAuth`, but it doesn't work. Can you help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `_fbAuth = async  () => ` ?

Comment: @PritishVaidya: YOU SAVED ME!!! Thanks a lot. it works. Can you post it as the answer so I can accept it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the function as

```
_fbAuth = async () => {}
```

Since `this` is not being referenced in `_fbAuth` function.

For more info checkout this [artice](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html)